# Map two lists into a dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary, ienumerable

**Given two** `IEnumerable`s **of the same size, how can I convert it to a** `Dictionary` **using Linq?**

```
IEnumerable<string> keys = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" };
IEnumerable<string> values = new List<string>() { "Val A", "Val B", "Val C" };

var dictionary = /* Linq ? */;
```

And the expected output is:

```
A: Val A
B: Val B
C: Val C
```

I wonder if there is some simple way to achieve it.

And should I be worried about performance? What if I have large collections?

---

I don't if there is an easier way to do it, currently I'm doing like this:

I have an Extension method that will loop the `IEnumerable` providing me the element and the index number.

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static void Each<T>(this IEnumerable els, Action<T, int> a)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (T e in els)
        {
            a(e, i++);
        }
    }
}
```

And I have a method that will loop one of the Enumerables and with the index retrieve the equivalent element on the other Enumerable.

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Merge<TKey, TValue>(IEnumerable<TKey> keys, IEnumerable<TValue> values)
{
    var dic = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();

    keys.Each<TKey>((x, i) =>
    {
        dic.Add(x, values.ElementAt(i));
    });

    return dic;
}
```

Then I use it like:

```
IEnumerable<string> keys = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" };
IEnumerable<string> values = new List<string>() { "Val A", "Val B", "Val C" };

var dic = Util.Merge(keys, values);
```

And the output is correct:

```
A: Val A
B: Val B
C: Val C
```

Answer (score 181, accepted):

With .NET 4.0 (or the 3.5 version of System.Interactive from Rx), you can use `Zip()`:

```
var dic = keys.Zip(values, (k, v) => new { k, v })
              .ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v);
```

Comment: Thumbs up for .Zip. Glad it's made it into the BCL. I've had my own version for quite some time.

Comment: @spender - Even if you made your own, i would take it from [Eric Lipperts Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/07/zip-me-up.aspx)

Comment: Pity there is a need for a `Zip` method. If only more statically typed languages would support generic variadic parameters, `Select` would handle this (like `map` in Scheme).

Comment: In 2022 it can be shorter as `var dic = keys.Zip(values).ToDictionary(x => x.First, x => x.Second);`

Comment: Just for reference, @Romulus' method in **VB.NET** would be: `Dim dic = keys.Zip(values).ToDictionary(Function(x) x.First, Function(x) x.Second)`.

Answer (score 36):

Or based on your idea, LINQ includes an overload of `Select()` that provides the index. Combined with the fact that `values` supports access by index, one could do the following:

```
var dic = keys.Select((k, i) => new { k, v = values[i] })
              .ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v);
```

(If `values` is kept as `List<string>`, that is...)

Answer (score 18):

I like this approach:

```
var dict =
   Enumerable.Range(0, keys.Length).ToDictionary(i => keys[i], i => values[i]);
```

Comment: I didn't realize it at first but both `Enumerable` and `Zip` are features of ***Linq***. Food for thought.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ), you can also utilize it's [ToDictionary](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/e8b307006f81fc585413230be938732f16fbf6ed/MoreLinq/ToDictionary.cs#L75) extension method on previously created `KeyValuePair`s:

```
var dict = Enumerable
    .Zip(keys, values, (key, value) => KeyValuePair.Create(key, value))
    .ToDictionary();
```

It also should be noted that using `Zip` extension method is safe against input collections of different lengths.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from .NET Core 3.0, you can just use the [improved Zip()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-zip-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-1)))) :

```
var dictionary = keys.Zip(values).ToDictionary(x => x.First, x => x.Second);
```

Define an extension method for this case, and you're as good as you can get :)