# Generic variadic parameters

Tags: c#, linq

From dahlbyk answer to this question : [Map two lists into a dictionary in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038978/map-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-c) , Leppie wrote this comment:

> Pity there is a need for a Zip method. If only more statically typed languages would support generic variadic parameters, Select would handle this (like map in Scheme). – leppie

What does that mean? (I don't know Scheme)   :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

He means, that if C# would support dynamic number or arguments (variadic, `params`) which are all of a different generic type, there wouldn't be a need for a `Zip` method, because it could be covered by `Select`.

I don't know if this is true, just interpreting the sentence ...

**Edit:**

I just think that he means a variable number of generic types (which is in fact only useful in combination with a variable number of method arguments), like this:

```
void Foo<params T>(params T[] args)

Foo(true, 7, "hello");
```

Just think about the many declarations of `Action<...>` and `Func<...>`.

By the way, when you are not sure about a comment, why not simply asking him?

Comment: +1 That would be nice, just like in [C++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Variadic_templates).

Comment: it is untrue that it is useful only with associated arguments. the types by themselves are an information. Foo<bool, string>() would allow us to make a typelist, using typeof. For example, to make a variant class.