# Constraint on params array of Types

Tags: c#

In the following method:

```
public void Foo(params Type[] types) {}
```

How can I constrain the `types` so that each `Type` passed in must derive from a certain base class?

I want something along the lines of this:

```
public void Foo(params Type[] types) where each types : BaseClass {}
```

---

**Clarification:**

I want the **types** of the classes that derive from `BaseClass`, not the instances of them.

For example if `Bar` is a subclass of `BaseClass`, I want to be able to pass in `typeof(Bar)`, not `new Bar()`.

Comment: Why not use `BaseClass` directly? `public void Foo(params BaseClass[] types) {}`?

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan Then it would be the instances of `BaseClass`, I want the types, not instances.

Comment: You can also pass `Type` instance if `Type` is subclass of `BaseClass`

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan I want the Type of the classes that derive from `BaseClass`, for example if `Bar` is the subclass of `BaseClass`, I want to be able to pass in `typeof(Bar)`, not `new Bar()`.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to check it in compile time. `typeof(Bar)` will return an instance of `System.Type`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417174/using-the-params-keyword-for-generic-parameters-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass an array of `Type` objects, than you can't do what you want. That's because constraints are part of the type system - you can set a method to get an argument of type `int`, or a generic method to receive a generic type parameter derived from `IDisposable`, or whatever, but what you have there is already a specific, concrete type - `Type`.

`Type`, confusingly, isn't part of the *type system*. It's just a regular class that happens to describe the *type system metadata*. But it's just any old class.

Being able to constrain a method to only accept a `Type` instance whose `BaseClass` property is `MyBaseClass` is just like being able to constrain a method to only accept `string` arguments whose `Length == 3` - it's not a question of *type* (as C# sees it), but of *data* inside those types.

Of course, it's not unheard of in other languages to be able to create constrained types - to create a type `TLA` which is a type of `string` which must be of length 3 - but that's not how C#'s type system (currently) works.

What you *can* do is use generic type parameters as a wrapper:

```
public void Foo<T1, T2, T3>() where T1 : BaseClass, T2:BaseClass, T3:BaseClass
{
   // call untyped Foo.
   Foo(typeof(T1), typeof(T2), typeof(T3));
}
```

This gives you stronger type safety for some scenarios, but it won't give you the ability to pass an unbounded list of types that a `params []` will.

This is conceptually similar to wrapping a method which accepts an `object` parameter with a typed wrapper method. If your `Add(object obj)` is confusing, hide it and expose `Add(int i) { Add((object)i);}` and `Add(string s) { Add((object)s);}`

Answer (score 1):

The standard kind of workaround here is to check types that are passed to the method and throw an exception if certain type is not what we expect it to be :

```
public void Foo(params Type[] types)
{  
     EnsureInheritedFrom<BaseClass>(types);

     // ...rest of stuff
}

private void EnsureInheritedFrom<TBaseType>(IEnumerable<Type> types)
{
     var targetType = typeof(TBaseType);
     foreach(Type type in types)
     {
         if(!targetType.IsAssignableFrom(type))
         {
             throw new ArgumentException(nameof(types), "Type {type.Name} is not supported!");
         }
     }   
}
```