# Generic method with many types

Tags: c#, generics, methods, overloading

If I want a generic method to have many generic types, e.g. up to 16.

Do I have to overload the method 16 times or is there any smarter way to do this?

```
public interface IMyInterface { }

public class MyClass {
    public void MyMethod<T1>() where T1 : IMyInterface { }
    public void MyMethod<T1, T2>() where T1 : IMyInterface where T2 : IMyInterface { }
    public void MyMethod<T1, T2, T3>() where T1 : IMyInterface where T2 : IMyInterface 
                                       where T3 : IMyInterface { }
    public void MyMethod<T1, T2, T3, T4>() where T1 : IMyInterface where T2 : IMyInterface 
                                           where T3 : IMyInterface where T4 : IMyInterface { }
    // All the way to T16...
    // Is there any smarter way of doing this
    // instead of having to write it 16 times?
}
```

Comment: Don't your methods have an implementation?

Comment: I didn't include any implementation to keep it simple. And I didn't think the implementation would be of any importance.

Comment: But then surely your implementation will be different for each method so you have to write it one way or another, no?

Comment: There is no way to generalize the generics if you asking about this so you have to either do it manually or use T4 templates to automate the boring procedure but final result will be still multiple overloads with different number of generics. The example of how to automate you can see there: http://blog.dreasgrech.com/2013/04/auto-generating-generic-tuple-classes.html

Comment: if all different generic parameters implement the same interface where is the need to distinguish them ?

Comment: Well imagine that the implementation is just a for-loop for each type, this way it could be implemented in one method

Comment: No, we don't have variadicts in C# sadly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you look at the documentation of [`Action<T1, T2, ....>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-10?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) it seems that you need to implement all overloads singlehandedly.

Here is the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/action.cs,a8bf5adf45b675da) of it. As you see it is done as in your example.

A more detailed answer as to why a `params` equivalent does not exist can be found by [Jon Skeet here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15417228/5174469).
It states:

"Fundamentally `Func<T>` and `Func<T1, T2>` are entirely unrelated types as far as the CLR is concerned, and there's nothing like params to specify multiple type arguments."

Comment: `there seems to be no necessity to distinguish between the types T1 and T2` That's not a generally correct assessment. It's correct for OP's current code (no return type etc) but OP has already mentioned that the code example is heavily redacted for simplicity's sake. There may be reason to keep the type. For example, consider `Tuple<T,U>` where is it relevant to distinguish between `T` (`Item1`) and `U` (`Item2`). Without tracking both types, you'd end up having to cast `Item1` and `Item2` to the correct type which is a minefield of exceptions and bad handling.

Comment: By including the 'where T1 : IMyInterface' I make sure that the method is used only by objects that implement the IMyInterface - interface and not any other object. Is this an incorrect use of the feature?

Comment: @Flater I understand your point. This is actually covered in the first part, and especially by the answer of Jon Skeet. `Tuple<T,U>` does not impose the constraint of having `T` AND `U` implement the same interface. This constraint makes it to the special case that I mentioned. I wil edit my post and try to be more precise

Comment: @DeadlyCow " Is this an incorrect use of the feature?" no I don't think that it is incorrect. If all objects or different types use this interface, then one type and one constraint should suffice. But this is just my theoretical thinking. because I cannot come up (so fast on the fly) with a scenario where the distinction between T1 and T2 is necessary. I am actually very intriguiged by this case and would like to see the real implementation

Comment: @MongZhu: The same argument would still apply for a `Tuple<T,U> where T : class where U : class` (or any other identifier such as `object` or `IFoo` or `BaseFoo`)