# Is there a way to have multiple signatures for a generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic class with a complex signature that I would like to simplify for convenience if all of the type parameters will be the same.

```
MyClass<T1, T2, T3, T4>
```

If all of the type parameters are Guid, I'd like to supply just one type parameter, the only way I can think of doing it would be to have another class defined.

```
MyClass<T1> : MyClass<T1, T1, T1, T1>
```

Is there a better method of achieving this functionality? Ultimately, I don't want there to be anything different between the classes other than the ability to use a simplified signature.

Comment: What is the problem on giving a **special** thing a **special** name, which is by creating a class for it that **specifically** assigns the generic parameters?

Comment: like `MyGuidClass  : MyClass<Guid, Guid, Guid, Guid>`...

Comment: You can put all the implementation in the one with 4 types and the other one will inherit all of that so no new code except for maybe a constructor if one is needed.

Comment: I don't want to give it a special name, because aside from the simplified signature, there is nothing special about it.

Comment: would that be a valid [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417174/using-the-params-keyword-for-generic-parameters-in-c-sharp) ??

Comment: the set of generic parameters is a part of the type signature. Chaging the amount of the parameters changes inavitalby the type. If you don't want a special name / different type, you are left with the 4 parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is the only way. As far as the compiler is concerned, `T1`, `T2`, `T3` and `T4` are unrelated.

Comment: If this is the only way, would it be considered a bad practice? I have all of the functionality defined in the class with the complex signature, the simplified class would not have any additional functionality.

Comment: Well, as far as opinions go, if, as you've said, there's nothing special about it, then yes. But I disagree that there's nothing special about it. If you can name it, it's special. `MyHomogeneousClass<T1> : MyClass<T1, T1, T1, T1>`, or `MyGuids : MyClass<T1, T1, T1, T1>` are both perfectly fine.

Comment: It's a generic MVC controller, the type parameters are the ViewModel types for the common actions, in most cases, the common actions use the same ViewModel, but for flexibility, I wanted to make it possible to define different ViewModel types for each action.

Comment: I stand by what I've said. There doesn't need to be any __extra__ functionality to make it special. You can make things special by restricting functionality. This may help when placing `MyClass` instances in a list and you want to constrain the T's or something like that. Anyway, this is becoming way too subjective for StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help; I'll try to find another forum to discuss the subjective side of the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is generally no way for the compiler to infer generic type parameters based on other generic type parameters. Therefore, you either have to specify all or nothing. If you refer to a class, you always have to specify all type parameters.

However, the compiler may have a chance to infer generic type parameters of methods from the passed parameters, so what you can do is something like

```
public MyClass<T, T, T, T> CreateMyClass<T>(T item)
```

If you provide an API like that so users don't have to rely on constructors, you may have a chance to keep explicit type parameters to a bare minimum.